# Why is the expected output not displayed

Tags: c, implicit-conversion, comparison-operators, unsigned-integer, signed-integer

why there is no output for this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    int array[4] = {10, 25, 36, 42};
    // int size=sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);
    for (i = -1; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(int); i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i+1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output is
10 25 36 42

Comment: It gets successfully compiled. But the expected output is not shown.

Comment: Why are you iterating from `-1`? I think, it's a negative value being casted to `size_t`.

Comment: @bereal Wow. gcc does not warn even with pedantic.

Comment: @bereal yeah. but I am not trying to print anything out of array.

Comment: @bereal It should at least warn that there is unreachable code!

Comment: The array size test should *also* be an `int` value, as: `(int)(sizeof(array) / sizeof(int))`.  This will help circumvent the ‘comparison of integer expressions of different signedness’ warning thrown by `-Wextra`.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica `-Wsign-compare` works for me, but `-Wall` doesn't :/

Comment: @bereal [gcc 13.2 apparently includes -Wsign-compare](https://www.godbolt.org/z/v9abbEoYx) Oh, for C++!

Comment: Didn't C++ change the rules about type alignment (or whatever the term is) in expressions? It would intuitively make more sense to make everything int as long as each operand of the comparison fits in an int.

Comment: Let's enumerate all the integers `i` such that `-1 <= i < 4` (in mathematical sense, not C sense). How many are those? My hand says {-1, 0, 1, 2, 3} makes 5 in total. Why do you expect 4 numbers to be printed?

Answer (score 3):

Within the conditional expression of the for loop

```
 for (i = -1; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(int); i++) {
```

the variable `i` having the signed type `int` is implicitly converted to the unsigned type `size_t` due to the usual arithmetic conversions because the expression `sizeof(array) / sizeof(int)` has the unsigned integer type `size_t` and the rank of the type `size_t` (that is usually an alias for the type `unsigned long`) is greater than the rank of the type `int`.

As a result the expression `( size_t )-1` (the variable `i` is set initially to `-1`) that is the left operand of the condition
`i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(int)` becomes a very big unsigned value due to propagating the sign bit.

Try for example this call of `printf`

```
printf( "( size_t )-1 = %zu\n", ( size_t )-1 );
```

So the condition of the if statement evaluates to logical false.

You could write for example

```
 for ( i = -1; i < ( int )( sizeof(array) / sizeof(int) ); i++) {
```

to get the expected result - to execute the for loop.

Though in any case the loop will invoke undefined behavior because when `i` will be equal to `( int )( sizeof(array) / sizeof(int) ) - 1` the expression `array[i+1]` will try to access memory beyond the defined array.

It will be much better and correct to write

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array); i++) {
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Comparing signed and unsigned values can lead to surprising behaviour.  You are effectively doing `(size_t)i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(int)`, and `(size_t)-1` is a huge number.

In this case, there's no reason to start with `i = -1`; this can be done correctly and more simply with `i = 0`, which avoids the problem at hand. (You attempted to loop once too many times anyway, and starting with `i = 0` also fixed that.)

ALWAYS enable your compiler's warnings. With gcc or clang, I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. It would have caught this.

Comment: Add `-Werror` so you won't be tempted to use code that compiles with warnings.

Comment: I'm not tempted to ignore warnings.

Comment: Me neither, but I make the compiler force my hand with `-Werror`.